# How to parse and substring from value

Tags: java, substring

i have question about how to parse data i have here the example

```
52=2020-04-02T06:07:23.213
```

what i expected get value

```
1. 2020-04-02
2. 2020-04-02 06:07:23.213
```

how to get them using parse and substring ?
because i want to save the data for format like this

```
EUR/USD|1.09595|2020-04-02 06:07:23.213 and EUR/USD|2020-04-02.text
```

regards,

Fuad

Answer (score 1):

You can use SimpleDateFormat in java

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.S").parse("2020-04-02T06:07:23.213");
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S").format(date));
```